# Referring Range with Known Columns and Unknown Rows Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

How do you refer to a range where the number of columns is known but you don't know which row? What's the correct way of rendering `Range("A&i:J&i")`?

```
For i = 8 To WSData.Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

        If Cells(i, 1) = "Overall Totals:" Then
            WSData.Range("A&i:J&i").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        End If

Next
```

Comment: `Range("A" & i & ":J" & i)`

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott's answer is off course quite correct. However there are several other ways of referring to a variable range which you might find useful.

1) You could also use `WSData.Range("A10", "J10")`, i.e. you specify the top left and bottom right cells as two separate parameters. (The order of the paraneters doesn't actually matter!)
In your example, you would use: WSData.Range("A" & i , "J" & i)

2) I find using numbers, rather than letters for columns is useful, especially if your columns will be unknown in advance. The basic structure is as follows.

```
WSData.Range(Cells(1,10), Cells(10,10) 'A10 to J10)
```

or in  your example

```
WSData.Range(Cells(1,i), Cells(10,i))
```

However one has to be careful! The default worksheet for the Cells range is the Active Worksheet. If this is not the same as the WSData, it will lead to a run time error. However, this can easily by avoided by specifying the worksheet to which the "Cells" belong:

```
WSData.Range(WSData.Cells(1,i), WSData.Cells(10,i))
```

This may look rather long-winded but it gives you complete flexibility in specifying your range as you can use variables for each of the cell parameters.